# Aligning text in ASP.net

Tags: html, css, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a asp.net table, and I am trying to format the text so it is positioned central in the tablecell tag using CSS however I am having problems getting the text to format at all below is my table code and CSS code:

Table:

```
  <nav>
                <ul style ="tr" id="menu">
                    <asp:Table text-align ="center" runat ="server" CssClass="navbar">
                    <asp:TableRow runat ="server">
                    <asp:TableCell>
                    <li style = text-align ="center">Shipping</li>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell >
                    <li>Rail &amp; Stocks</li>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell >
                    <li>Manning Records</li>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                    <li>Update Tables</li>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                    <li>Reports</li>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow >
                    <asp:TableRow runat="server">
                    <asp:TableCell>
                    <li>Quality Problems</li>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                    <li>Working Time regulations</li>
                     </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                    </asp:Table>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar
{
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This errors is usually can only solve by you, using your browser debug tools. There, looking your final rendered page, you manually and online change your css and see what you have done wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters, part of your styling code is wrong, and as such will throw off your CSS styling. For example, this should be:

```
<li style="text-align:center">
```

However, as you are defining this in the CSS file, there should be no need (unless you have         li tags defined elsewhere in your CSS).

Plus you are also trying to set the style of the ASP table within the markup of the control, you cannot do this to my knowledge.

It should be something along the lines of

```
<asp:Table ID="myTable" runat="server" CssClass="navbar">
```